# Google App Engine Fails with "FilterChain is a restricted class"

Tags: google-app-engine

When attempting to run a Java application in the local Google App Engine instance I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.servlet.FilterChain is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

My `RemoteServiceServlet` doesn't contain any reference to the `FilterChain` class.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer (or at least, **an answer**) to this question before posting it, but thought that it was worth putting it onto SO for anyone else who has the same problem. The solution was to revert back to an earlier JDK. I was using 1.7.0_55, and when I went back to 1.7.0_21 the problem went away. I found the solution [here](http://jiggermast.blogspot.com/2014/05/google-appengine-devserver.html). Using Eclipse the JDK version can be changed in the Debug Configurations dialog, on the JRE tab.